# A task was canceled exception upon exception in SendMailAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task

I am working on a MVC application. My APIs are written in ASP.NET MVC Web API. I make a call to API on button click. MVC Controller code on button click is:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
        string responseFromApi = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (responseFromApi.Length > 1)
        {
            // My logic
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

I am sending email from my API:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddOrder(CustomerOrder order)
{
    try
    {
        await sendEmail(orderNumber, order.EmailId);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 0);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {   
    }
}
```

sendEmail method is:

```
private async Task sendEmail(string orderNumber, string clientEmailId)
    {
        //SmtpClient smtp = null;
        //int response = 0;
        try
        {
            string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
            int portNumber = 587;
            bool enableSSL = true;
            string emailFromAddress = "email"; //Sender Email Address  
            string password = "password"; //Sender Password  
            string emailToAddress = clientEmailId; //Receiver Email Address  
            string subject = "Subject";
            string body = $"Body";

            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFromAddress);
                mail.To.Add(emailToAddress);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("D:\\TestFile.txt"));//--Uncomment this to send any attachment  
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
                {   
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFromAddress, password);
                    smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
                }
                
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now, if there is any exception in the **sendEmail** method like (i turned off the internet on my development machine) i will get "A task was canceled" exception on MVC controller side (Client). If there is no exception in **sendEmail** method then everything works fine.

What is the possible issue here ? I am just stuck and unable to find any solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code which has resolved the issue for me for the time being is:

```
private async Task sendEmail(string orderNumber, string clientEmailId)
{
    try
    {
        string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int portNumber = 587;
        bool enableSSL = true;
        string emailFromAddress = "email"; //Sender Email Address  
        string password = "password"; //Sender Password  
        string emailToAddress = clientEmailId; //Receiver Email Address  
        string subject = "Subject";
        string body = $"Body";

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFromAddress);
            mail.To.Add(emailToAddress);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("D:\\TestFile.txt"));//--Uncomment this to send any attachment  
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {   
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFromAddress, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                //await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
                await Task.Run(async () => await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail));
            }
                
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Can someone kindly explain me why the first approach is not working and second one is working .

Comment: This looks like a timeout. Have you used an HTTP debugger (like Fiddler) to see if the HTTP call is actually started and completed? By, the way, `HttpClient` instances are supposed to be reused.

Comment: Issue is basically with "SendMailAsync" method @PauloMorgado

Comment: @PauloMorgado i have update the question. Can you kindly have a look at it

Comment: @PauloMorgado i have mentioned in the question how my issue is resolved for the time being. I think i am really mixing up something with Task/await. Can you kindly look at both the approaches and suggest

Comment: @Waleed: in the 'AddOrder' method, if an exception occurs (e.g. in the SendMail' method), you catch that exception. But your exception handler is empty, So you don't return a valid response to the API-request. Propably that is handled clientside with a 'Task is canceled exception in the 'PostAsync' method.

Comment: I am catching the exception in sendEmail method, so there is no chance that it will come to catch block of AddOrder @PauloMorgado . . . from google what i came to know is that there is something happening with using and await . .  I have even posted the solution but i just didn't get it completely . . So that's why looking for help

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?